# Create a directed graph using python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have 2 Node types, where TypeA will always point to TypeB, TypeB has no outbound edges.

How can I indicate this as a directed graph using igraph?

Comment: Can you be a little less vague? Include your code and what you have tried  so far. What problem did you face?

Comment: I think his question was pretty darn clear. And the answer is exactly what I expected. Maybe you just didn’t understand the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/generation.html#from-nodes-and-edges

```
g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(2)
g.add_edges([(0,1)])
g.degree(mode="in")     # -> [0, 1]
g.degree(mode="out")    # -> [1, 0]
```